# Loading COM Object in silverlight 4

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

Can any one tell me how to load com object in a silverlight out of browser application  . I use silverlight4 . If possible can any one give me sample codes of it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are looking to find out how to use a com object in a SL4 OOB that already on the machine or are looking to see how you can install (load) one via the browser?

Comment: i am looking on how to load dll via the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the System.Windows.Interop.ComAutomationFactory (new in Silverlight 4).

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.comautomationfactory(VS.96).aspx

Don't be too shocked if you find it hard to get it to work on a mac :-)